# Parsing Xml files created by Gate

Tags: xml-parsing, gate

I'm new in Gate Developer 8.1 and wonder if anybody knows how could we parse the .xml files which is created after annotating texts. I need to extract annotated data with their offsets which is highlighted by our annotators

Thanks,

Comment: See the official answer here: https://sourceforge.net/p/gate/mailman/message/34912604/